# Add datetime in filename and remove spaces

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to add datetime in my filename as shown below:

```
User_Call_Detail_20210406_20210407000004.csv
```

where `20210406` is the (current date - 1) and `20210407000004` is the current date with timestamp and `User Call Detail.csv` is my filename. I want to make the filename as shown above.

Can anyone please help in achieving this as I am new in development.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a regular expression, like the one below:

`^(.*)_(\d+)_(\d+)\.csv$`

You could then use the `re` module to parse the sample string:

```py
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"^(.*)_(\d+)_(\d+)\.csv$")
>>> match = regex.search("User_Call_Detail_20210406_20210407000004.csv")
>>> groups = match.groups()
>>> groups
('User_Call_Detail', '20210406', '20210407000004')
```

Comment: I want to make the file name as User_Call_Detail_20210406_20210407000004.csv But in this case it is separating the date file name and current date.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
    
t = datetime.date.today()
    
y = (t - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
    
ts = round(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())
    
print (y.strftime("%Y%m%d"),t.strftime("%Y%m%d"),ts)
```

Output:

```
20210413 20210414 1618410896
```